# failed to Executing Ant script: weblogic-appc.build.xml

Tags: java, pom.xml

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal maven.plugins:weblogic-appc-maven-plugin:1.0.83:ejb-clients-zip (ejb-clients-zip) on project . Failed to execute: Executing Ant script: weblogic-appc.build.xml [ejb-clients-zip]: Failed to execute. The following error occurred while executing this line:

[ERROR] C:\Users\..path\target\.ant-mojo\weblogic-appc.build.xml:87: The following error occurred while executing this line:

[ERROR] C:\Users\..path\target\.ant-mojo\weblogic-appc.build.xml:124: The following error occurred while executing this line:

[ERROR] C:\Users\..path\target\.ant-mojo\weblogic-appc.build.xml:151: Java returned: 1
```

I tried to execute `mvn clean install` but getting above error. I don't know, is there any Ant version issue or what?